# BindingSource.Count always display as 1 unless it is not null VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I'm developing a program to keep stocks. I need to Update the stock of table if the ShoeID and Size are already excisting.Otherwise it should add a new row.

When I enter data, if the same shoeID and Size in previous record, it updates. But if I add the record after some records it creates a new record. Does not update the previous record.

```
Private Sub AddStockBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddStockBtn.Click
    Dim Size, Stock As Integer
    Dim stock_check As String
    Dim status As Boolean = False
    stock_check = "Pending"
    StockBindingSource.ResetBindings(True)

    Try
        Size = Integer.Parse(SizeTxt.Text)
        Stock = Integer.Parse(StockTxt.Text)
        Console.WriteLine(stock_check)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Size or Stock")
    End Try

    If (StockBindingSource.Count = 0) Then
        StockBindingSource.AddNew()
        StockBindingSource.Current("No") = 1
        StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeID") = IDBox.Text
        For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
            Dim rowData As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
            If rowData("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text Then
                StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeType") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Type")
                StockBindingSource.Current("Description") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Name")
            End If
        Next
        StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size
        StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = Stock
        StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
        TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
            Dim rowName As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
            If rowName("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text And StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size Then
                StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") + Stock
                StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
                TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
                status = True
            End If
            Console.WriteLine(ShoeDataBindingSource.Count)
            stock_check = "Loop"
        Next

        If (Not status And stock_check = "Loop") Then
            Dim no As Integer
            no = StockBindingSource.Count + 1
            StockBindingSource.AddNew()
            StockBindingSource.Current("No") = no
            StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeID") = IDBox.Text
            For i As Integer = 0 To ShoeDataBindingSource.Count - 1
                Dim rowData As DataRowView = ShoeDataBindingSource.Item(i)
                If rowData("ShoeID").ToString = IDBox.Text Then
                    StockBindingSource.Current("ShoeType") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Type")
                    StockBindingSource.Current("Description") = ShoeDataBindingSource.Current("Name")
                End If
            Next
            StockBindingSource.Current("Size") = Size
            StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = Stock
            StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
            TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I enter my data First time
[image: First Data enter]

Updated same data
[image: Second]

Add an another data and added the same data again,
[image]

New Data Updates here
[image]

Hope you understood the problem. Somebody help please.

StockBindingSource.count does not update. It always shows as 1, unless it is  null.

Comment: Best to attempt setting break-points, debug the code to see if you can detect the issue. Conceptually speaking one should work off the underlying data source. I tried to paste the example in here but it's too long so I am posting it as an answer even thou it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above in regards to my attempt to post this code into a comment.

```
Dim ShoeId As Integer = 1
Dim ShoeSize As Integer = 15
Dim Stock As Integer = 1
Dim thisRow As DataRow = Nothing

Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
               {
                   .ColumnName = "Id",
                    .DataType = GetType(Integer),
                    .AutoIncrement = True,
                    .AutoIncrementSeed = 1
                })

dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
               {
                    .ColumnName = "ShoeId",
                    .DataType = GetType(Integer),
                    .AutoIncrement = True
                })

dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
               {
                   .ColumnName = "Size",
                   .DataType = GetType(Integer)
               })

dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
               {
                   .ColumnName = "ShoeType",
                   .DataType = GetType(String)
               })
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
               {
                   .ColumnName = "Stock",
                   .DataType = GetType(Integer)
               })
dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, 1, 15, "Shoe", 5})


bs.DataSource = dt
thisRow =
    (
        From t In CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable).AsEnumerable
        Where t.Field(Of Integer)("ShoeId") = ShoeId AndAlso t.Field(Of Integer)("Size") = ShoeSize
        Select t).FirstOrDefault

If thisRow IsNot Nothing Then
    thisRow.SetField(Of Integer)("Stock", thisRow.Field(Of Integer)("Stock") + 1)
Else
    ' add
End If

ShoeId = 2
ShoeSize = 15
thisRow =
    (
        From t In CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable).AsEnumerable
        Where t.Field(Of Integer)("ShoeId") = ShoeId AndAlso t.Field(Of Integer)("Size") = ShoeSize
        Select t).FirstOrDefault

If thisRow IsNot Nothing Then
    thisRow.SetField(Of Integer)("Stock", thisRow.Field(Of Integer)("Stock") + 1)
Else
    CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, ShoeId, ShoeSize, "Shoe", 5})
End If

ShoeId = 1
ShoeSize = 15
thisRow =
    (
        From t In CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable).AsEnumerable
        Where t.Field(Of Integer)("ShoeId") = ShoeId AndAlso t.Field(Of Integer)("Size") = ShoeSize
        Select t).FirstOrDefault

If thisRow IsNot Nothing Then
    thisRow.SetField(Of Integer)("Stock", thisRow.Field(Of Integer)("Stock") + 1)
Else
    CType(bs.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Add(New Object() {Nothing, ShoeId, ShoeSize, "Shoe", 5})
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Really appreciate it. Can you explain me what `bs.DataSource = dt` is.

Comment: bs is a BindingSource. I am setting the DataSource to a DataTable variable named dt. As mentioned this is conceptual as I put a bunch of code together which would normally be in different methods which is why I cast the DataSource of the BindingSource even thou dt is visible, you would need to do this when dt is not visible as a variable. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Karen. But in my code, I just use the default bindingsources for the dataset and I need to update the dataset. If the same ID and the Size is exist new value should replace the old value and if it is not it sould create a new record. I tried it using your code. But I could not do that. :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an easy way to complete the task. Thanks Karen for help.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In StockDataGrid.Rows
            Dim tempID As String = row.Cells(1).Value
            Dim tempSize As String = row.Cells(3).Value
            If tempID = IDBox.Text And tempSize = Size Then
                StockBindingSource.Position = count
                StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") = StockBindingSource.Current("Stock") + Stock
                StockBindingSource.EndEdit()
                TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(SilexDatabaseDataSet)
                status = True
            End If
            count = count + 1
        Next
```

This way, I could solve my problem. I used a datagridview.